# primefaces p:messages are not displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a button in a form and I want an error message to be displayed when I click on this button. It is a step I want to complete before coding something similar. My code does not work because the error message is not displayed when I click on the button.

My form is:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:messages id="errorMessage" for="myForm" autoUpdate="true" />
    <p:fieldset id="myFieldSet"
                style="margin-left:auto ; margin-right:auto ; width:98% ; height:90px;">
        <p:outputLabel for="numSi"
                       value="Value :"
                       style="margin-left:31px;margin-top:25px;" />
        <p:inputText id="numSi"
                     value="#{suppSiBean.researchValue}"
                     maxlength="9" required="true">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton id="suppSignaButton" type="submit" ajax="true"
                         value="Launch"
                         style="text-align: center ; height:45px; width:150px ; margin-top:20px;"
                        action="#{suppSiBean.lancerRequete()}" />
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

Excerpt of my bean :

```
public void lancerRequete() {}
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    //I'm intentionally hide the values of the three following variables because it's confidential
    ResourceBundle bundle = ...
    String message = ...
    String messageFormat = ...
    FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, messageFormat.toString(), "");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(getClientId("myForm"), facesMessage);
}

public String getClientId(String id) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    UIComponent c = findComponent(root, id);
    LOGGER.info("c.getClientId(context) vaut :" + c.getClientId(context));
    return c.getClientId(context);
}

private UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent c, String id) {
    if (id.equals(c.getId())) {
        return c;
    }
    Iterator<UIComponent> kids = c.getFacetsAndChildren();
    while (kids.hasNext()) {
        UIComponent found = findComponent(kids.next(), id);
        if (found != null) {
            return found;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not targeting the ID of the component directly in the `addMessage` method ?

```
public void lancerRequete() {}
     ...
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("errorMessage", facesMessage);
}
```

Finally, you should tell when to update this component by adding `update` attribute :

```
<p:commandButton ... update="errorMessage" />
```

Comment: There's already an `autoUpdate="true"`, which you haven't explained why it didn't work. The mistake is elsewhere and you can figure out it by running and debugging the provided code yourself.

Comment: The code in the question, of course. Your code works fine, but doesn't explain OP's problem nor answer it.

Comment: It seems `autoUpdate` couldn't work for him, but maybe `update="..."` does and thus answers his question.

Comment: Nope, it won't (because `autoUpdate` already didn't work). As said, the mistake is elsewhere and you can figure out it by running and debugging the provided code yourself.

Comment: Ok ok, could you so find out where could be the trouble ? ; )

Comment: And you can when you try to reproduce the problem based on information provided so far (and you will learn things from questions and become a better JSF developer this way).

Comment: Use this please: <p:messages id="errorMessage" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

Comment: Hmm, many code, but addMessage() only needs a String referencing the `for=` attribute and a FacesMessage.
`....addMessage("myForm", facesMessage);` "myForm" references the for-attribute, not the form-id. You should use different names.